# How to return the date of the first month with a negative value in excel

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, lookup

I am doing a valuation of a company using excel, and I am struggling with the following:

The layout of the sheet is as follows (simplified for obvious reasons)

|  | Jan '23. | Feb '23. | March '23. |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Cash bal | 200 | 300 | -100 |
| Runway end | x. |  |  |

I am trying to find a formula that will return the date when the runway ends (in this case x should be March '23) And if the runway never ends (i.e. the cash bal never goes negative) return "none"

I tried an if function:

```
= if(range of cash bal < 0, range of months, "none")
```

This didn't work as it just returned "none" due to the fact it would only search the first column.

I have tried an H-lookup and x-lookup and also not been successful.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show us what you tried? (ie: show us the X-lookup and/or h-lookup formulas you have tried)

Comment: Are the `Jan '23 Feb '23. March '23.` dates, or text?

Answer (score 1):

Use INDEX/AGGREGATE:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(range of months,AGGREGATE(15,7,(COLUMN(range of cash bal)-MIN(COLUMN(range of cash bal))+1)/(range of cash bal<0),1)),"NONE")
```

Or with Office 365 Excel:

```
=TAKE(FILTER(range of months,range of cash bal<0,"NONE"),,1)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `XLOOKUP`

```
=XLOOKUP(TRUE,range_of_cash_bal<0,range_of_months,"none")
```

[image]

*If you do not have the `XLOOKUP` function, you can use `IFERROR(INDEX/MATCH`*

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(range_of_months, MATCH(TRUE,range_of_cash_bal<0,0)),"none")
```